# How much rep do you need to be able to edit tags more easily?

Tags: support, editing, retagging, privileges

On a site on which I have a high rep score, I am able to edit tags easily using the "Edit tags" button:

> [image: With Edit tags]

However, on this site (at time of writing), I have < 3000 rep, which is not enough to see the "Edit tags" button:

> [image: Without Edit tags]

I have been unable to track down any information on what rep score you need to unlock the "Edit tags" button. How much rep do I need before I can see this?

Comment: I didn't read that tag correctly; of course this is a [[tag:support]] question, not [[tag:feature-request]] (I think I somehow misremembered it as "[feature]", as in, "I'm asking about a feature", as per the support tag description). I feel I should know better...

Comment: The usual answer would be to look in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/222298 , but it happens to not explicitly answer this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Privileges page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) you need 10k for the [access to moderator tools](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.

> #### Inline tag editing
>
> Finally, you now have the ability to do inline tag edits on questions: a new "Edit tags" link will appear next to the tags on every question; clicking it brings up an inline editor for the tags on that question:

Comment: That's the one! I would have never associated it with mod tools, but in hindsight I can see how it could be thought of as one. Usually I'd wait longer to accept, but this is one of those "open-close" questions with only one right answer. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanS the privilege titles aren’t entirely accurate for everything they cover.